# Getting a sharp libvips npm install error (MacOS)

Tags: node.js, npm, gatsby, npm-install, sharp

I am trying to run npm install for my Gatsby project on macOS Ventura.

sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

I've looked through all of the previous tickets relating to this error and tried the fixes. For example, I've tried deleting the tar.br file (previous post had tar.bg), installing vips via HomeBrew, and installing sharp via npm and sharp (npm failed but yarn worked after some tinkering).

I have node version 18.9 and sharp version 0.31.1. This is what I have set in my package.json: "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.3.5", "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.7"

Any help is appreciated! Thank you so much!!

The error seems to be coming from the gatsby-transformer-sharp module:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/seanshe/Desktop/bdab_website/node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o
npm ERR!   LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/nothing.a
npm ERR!   TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
npm ERR! info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.10.5/libvips-8.10.5-darwin-arm64v8.tar.br
npm ERR! ERR! sharp Prebuilt libvips 8.10.5 binaries are not yet available for darwin-arm64v8
npm ERR! info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
npm ERR! info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@19.4.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.9 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/seanshe/Desktop/bdab_website/node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp/node_modules/sharp/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/seanshe/Library/Caches/node-gyp/19.4.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/seanshe/Library/Caches/node-gyp/19.4.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/seanshe/Library/Caches/node-gyp/19.4.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/seanshe/Desktop/bdab_website/node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp/node_modules/sharp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/libtool: archive library: Release/nothing.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
npm ERR! ../src/common.cc:24:10: fatal error: 'vips/vips8' file not found
npm ERR! #include <vips/vips8>
npm ERR!          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.4.0/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/seanshe/Desktop/bdab_website/node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v19.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/seanshe/.npm/_logs/2023-01-11T05_40_20_443Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that prebuilt libvips 8.10.5 binaries are not available for the architecture "darwin-arm64v8" and it's attempting to build from source via node-gyp.

To resolve the issue, you can follow the steps mentioned in the sharp installation guide: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install and install the required dependencies. It may also be helpful to check if your version of Node.js is compatible with the latest version of the sharp package.